# Assigning column of first data frame to the second one, if data frames have different size

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,301),columns = ['id'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(200,387),columns = ['id'])

df1['2'] = np.random.randint(0,2,301)
df2['2'] = np.random.randint(0,2,187)
```

Then I match id's from second data frame to first and create third df:

```
temp = df2.loc[df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]
```

Then I calculate some value:

```
def values_14(row):
    if row['2'] == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


temp['val'] = temp.apply(lambda row: values_14(row),axis = 1)
```

My question is: how can I assign values from the column `val` of data frame `temp` to the first data frame(if `id` in first data frame didn't match to the `id` of `temp`, then assign NA) in **general**? By in general I mean the situation, when `id` column, for example, are names and they are not sorted like a numbers. How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign a column in `df1` with `NA` by default. Next for each row in `df1` get `id` value for the `row` and look if same `id` is in `temp` `dataframe`. If it returns non empty then assign corresponding row of `df1` with first of values returned from `temp`. You can try following: (*np refers to the numpy*)

```
# setting empty nan column for 'val' in df1
df1['val'] = np.nan

# iterate through each row in df1
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # look for corresponding rows in temp dataframe 
    # that matches id of current row of df1
    val_df = temp.loc[temp['id'] == row['id']]
    # if id matched in temp then it will return non-empty
    if not val_df.empty:
         # assign corresponding row of df1 with first value 
         # of temp which where id matched
        df1.loc[index, 'val'] = val_df['val'].values[0]
```

Comment: Let me ask a couple questions:

1)val_df = temp.loc[temp['id'] == row['id']] this line compares(True of False) row['id'] with every value of temp['id'] at the same time?

2)df1.loc[index, 'val'] = val_df['val'].values[0] here can you please explain me why do we need to code values[0] from the RHS?

Comment: @Mat_nekras For `1)` yes, it will have `True or False` after comparison. For `2)` , `val_df['val']` returns `Series`,  so, `.values` changes it to `ndarray` and `.values[0]`, picks the first element from the array. There may be other alternatives and efficient ways as well.

Comment: Just one problem appears: when id values are stings, the code doesn't work. I says, that indexing should be integer or slicing, but not strings